# Print a text in a certain way (map/table) in java

Tags: java, string, format, tabular

I'm trying to print some text in this format:

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 : someone1 someone2 
 5 : someone1 someone2 : someone3
 6 : someone1 someone2 : someone3
 7 : someone1 someone2
 8  
 9  
10 : someone4 someone5 : someone6
11 : someone4 someone5 : someone6 : someone7 : someone8
12 : someone4 someone5 : someone6 : someone7 : someone8
13 : someone4 someone5 :          : someone7 : someone8
14 : someone4 someone5 :          : someone7 : someone8
15 : someone4 someone5 :          : someone7
16 : someone4 someone5 : someone9 someone10
17 : someone4 someone5 : someone9 someone10
18 :                   : someone9 someone10
```

Where People with the **same x2-x1** are the **same family**. Example: someone4 and someone5 (s4_x1 = s5_x1 && s4_x2 == s5_x2), Inhabitants with **overlapping intervals** are displayed in **parallel columns**, if two or more members of the family **start in the same x1 value**, the family with **largest house** ( x2-x1+1 ) appears on the **left side**. Each place occupied by a family must be separated by a colon. (See example above)

- Class Street -> Has a List of Families
- Class Family -> Has a List of People, x1 and x2.
- Class Person -> Has a name

Having a HashMap with **key** : position(x coord) and **value** : List (list of families in the coord), I can, for each x, sort the value by x1 (and if they are the same, then sort by house size ( x2-x1+1 ) ). Then I print, but the result will be:

```
 1 
 2 
 3 
 4 : someone1 someone2 
 5 : someone1 someone2 : someone3
 6 : someone1 someone2 : someone3
 7 : someone1 someone2
 8  
 9  
10 : someone4 someone5 : someone6
11 : someone4 someone5 : someone6 : someone7 : someone8
12 : someone4 someone5 : someone6 : someone7 : someone8
13 : someone4 someone5 : someone7 : someone8
14 : someone4 someone5 : someone7 : someone8
15 : someone4 someone5 : someone7
16 : someone4 someone5 : someone9 someone10
17 : someone4 someone5 : someone9 someone10
18 : someone9 someone10
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What does your input look like.   And you want advice on how to store it or how to print it out from what have stored?

Comment: How to print it out from what I stored. I just add people to the street (make a new family or add to an existing one if x1 and x2 matches) using my add method implemented on street class.